# Captcha on iPhone.

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdata, captcha, nsinputstream

I have a website, require input username, pass and captcha to login.

Now, I develop an application on iPhone to login that website.

I don't know how to get that captcha and show on iphone. 
I can get that Captcha in **NSData** and convert it into **NSInputStream**. But how can show image from InputStream in iOS?

In Android, I finished application with same function. I use:

`Drawable.createFromStream(inputstream, source)` to show Image on Android.

What function in iOS similar to createFromStream?

Should have parameter source, because my captcha is in that source.
Thanks.

Comment: It is different to my case. I get captcha from my server, and can't see it in text. In page of captcha, have a hidden token, so if I show captcha from URL with image, I can't store that token. If don't have that token, after sign in, can't access next page. If access url captcha 2 times, it means different captcha and token too. So, in my case, only get by NSData or NSInputStream to show captcha.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can display images from the web:

```
UIImage *web_image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:SET_YOUR_URL_HERE]]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an `UIImage` from a `NSData` object using `[UIImage imageWithData:data]` ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageWithData%3a)). Then display it in an `UIImageView`.

Or you could use a `UIWebView` to display the image directly or in a web page.

Comment: Yes, I did like that before asking. But [UIImage imageWithData:data] don't have source parameter. I mean my captcha image is from "src" in data, like this command in Android: Drawable.createFromStream(inputstream, "src"); In iOS have a function like that?